# Summarise all values of a column into a vector

Tags: r, tibble

So here is something I'm still trying to get right.

Imagine a tibble like this one:

```
library(tidyverse)
t1 <- tibble(
  id       = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
  id_sub   = c(1,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,2),
  position = c(1,2,1,2,1,1,2,3,4),
  head     = c(1,1,2,2,1,3,2,2,3)
  )
```

What I want to achieve is to create a 5th attribute `depend` that has the values from `head` for each `id_sub`. This does mean, that each value of `depend` is a vector with a minimum length of 1 (shouldn't be a problem with tibble, right?).

The result I'm looking for in this example would have an attribute with the following vectors:

```
c(1,1),c(2,2),c(1),c(3,2,2,3)
```

Of course my data is a little bigger and so far the only solution I was able to find was grouping the tibble and spreading `position` and `head`:

```
t1 %>% 
  group_by(id, id_sub) %>% 
  spread(position, head)
```

This of course creates multiple attributes:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Groups:   id, id_sub [4]
     id id_sub   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`
* <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1      1     1     1    NA    NA
2     1      2     2     2    NA    NA
3     2      1     1    NA    NA    NA
4     2      2     3     2     2     3
```

For just one sample I could transform `position`x`head` as a matrix and turn it into a vector ignoring `NA`. But this doesn't help me on a larger scale.

```
m <- t1 %>% 
  filter(id == 2 & id_sub == 2) %>% 
  select(-c(id,id_sub)) %>% 
  spread(position, head) %>% 
  as.matrix()
m <- as.vector(m)
m[!is.na(m)]
```

With the following result:

```
[1] 3 2 2 3
```

Happy to hear your thoughts and suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another possible solution:

```
t1 %>% 
  group_by(data.table::rleid(id_sub)) %>% 
  summarise(hd = list(head)) %>% 
  pull(hd)
```

which gives:

> ```
> [[1]]
> [1] 1 1
>
> [[2]]
> [1] 2 2
>
> [[3]]
> [1] 1
>
> [[4]]
> [1] 3 2 2 3
> ```

Comment: I think this is the better solution, easier to keep the relation between `id_sub` and the result if you add `id_sub` to the `group_by` statement.

Comment: @Florian thx, adding `id_sub` to the grouping is indeed better; imo my answer isn't better, it's just a somewhat different approach

Comment: Also just using `hd = list(head)` in `summarise` suffices already.

Answer (score 4):

Does this do what you want?

```
library(data.table)
split(t1$head, rleid(t1$id_sub))
```

Output:

```
$`1`
[1] 1 1

$`2`
[1] 2 2

$`3`
[1] 1

$`4`
[1] 3 2 2 3
```